# IOS UITableview in Storyboard cell's elements frame size and height shows zero

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, ios6

I am creating an TableView and creating its cells as follows

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"raffel";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
UIView *Imv=(UIView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
UILabel *Title=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:101];
UITextView *TicketDetails=(UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:102];
UILabel *BDprice=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:103];
UILabel *USDprice=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:104];
UILabel *TickRema=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:105];

NSLog(@"fram %@",Imv);
```

and the log shows

```
fram <UIView: 0x1ed91bd0; frame = (0 171; 0 0); autoresize = TM+BM; tag = 100; layer = <CALayer: 0x1ed91c30>>
```

it shows zero height and width but actuall height*width is 100*100

Answer (score 0):

implement this method in your code..

```
- (CGFloat) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
   return 100;
}
```